# SQL Server Encryption (TLS) - Internal CA (Trusted Root)

Tags: sql-server, ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority, certificate-store

I have configured an SQL 2022 Std instance with a certificate issued via an Internal CA.

[Sql Server TLS Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/certificate-overview?view=sql-server-ver16#digital-certificate-overview)

As per the above documentation, I was expecting that the certificate would need to be

> added to the trusted root certificate store on all client computers and devices

However after both CA & SQL certificates are imported to Trusted Root Certification Authorities successfully on the client, and testing with client connections set to encrypt I receive the error:

> The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted

I'm aware that I can set *trustservercertificate* to true on the connections and have confirmed as documented in [SQL Server Verify Network Encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-sql-server-encryption?view=sql-server-ver16#verify-network-encryption) the connections are encrypted when this setting is true.

Does the error indicate a misconfiguration?

Below shows the SQL Server binding.

[image: SQL Binding]

And an extract from sqlcheck as per the MS documentation: [Certificate Requirements for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/certificate-requirements?view=sql-server-ver16#check-if-a-certificate-meets-the-requirements)

[image: extract sqlcheck]

I also note from that article:

> Starting with SQL Server 2019 (15.x), SQL Server Configuration Manager automatically validates all certificate requirements during the configuration phase itself. If SQL Server successfully starts after you configure a certificate, it's a good indication that SQL Server can use that certificate

Server starts fine and shows connections are encrypted when the client is forced to trust the server certificate.

FYI I'm testing with SSMS v19 as the client.

The documentation here [SQL Server - Client Encryption Summary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-and-client-encryption-summary?view=sql-server-ver16) seems a little ambiguous as both internal ca scenarios (highlighted) refer to a company's certificate server, but only 1 imports the cert on the client and the other (which appears to be me) must set *trustservercertificate*?

[image: client encryption summary]

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: You don't need the instance's certificate in Trusted Roots on connecting clients, only the public key certificate of the Intermediate CA or the CA Root. It sounds like you've forgotten a critical step somewhere - such as actually going into SQL Server Configuration Manager and binding the new certificate to the instance and then restarting the instance for the changes to take effect. Have you double-checked [Certificate requirements for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/certificate-requirements)?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thanks for clarifying that. I do have the CA Root in the local Trusted Authorities and have checked the documentation you reference - i've updated the post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error has disappeared and I am now able to establish encrypted connections from the client without specifying *trustservercertificate=true*

I have not changed any configuration settings to resolve this however the VM hosting the sql server instance had been shut down and restarted.

I had previously restarted the SQL Server Service multiple times after configuring the certificate.